# Optimising *ngFor loops and *ngIf for large datasets (Angular 2)

Tags: angular

I'm displaying data JSON data (from an API) using *ngFor and I'm a bit concerned about possible performance issues in my approach. So I'm looking for suggestions on how to improve it.

This is the JSON structure (without data) that I am displaying in my page: https://gist.github.com/fogofogo/f4b5ac9a765fc684e7e08b30221c6419

And this the JSON structure with full data: https://gist.github.com/fogofogo/f7b5c3db347246689ea5007344eff53b

The JSON is only showing data for two matches and its already at 2k lines! It could potentially have 100 matches.

This is what I am using to display the data on a page:

```
<div class="..." *ngFor="let sport of competition.sports">

  <p>{{ sport.sport }}</p>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let country of sport.countries">

    <div class="..." *ngFor="let tournament of country.tournaments">

      <p>{{ country.country }} - {{ tournament.tournament }}</p>

      <div class="..." *ngFor="let fixture of tournament.fixtures" class="tournament_item">

        <p>{{fixture.homeTeam.name}} V {{fixture.awayTeam.name}}</p>

        <ng-container *ngFor="let market of fixture.markets">

          <ng-container *ngIf="market.marketId === 1">

            <div class="..."  *ngFor="let marketOption of market.marketOptions">
          {{ marketOption.fractionOdds }}
            </div>

          </ng-container>

        </ng-container>

      </div>

    </div>

  </ng-container>

</div>
```

And I get the data from the controller like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
   this.id = params['competitionId'];
   this.service.get(this.id)
  .subscribe(competition => this.competition = competition)
});
}
```

Apart from the ridiculous amount of ngFors (which feels wrong), I'm particularly concerned with this `*ngIf="market.marketId === 1"`. I could need to check over 20 markets in 100 matches. When I run this code in a browser with 250 matches it takes about 5 seconds to load.

If anyone could offer some advice on how I could optimise this I would appreciate it. Apologies for any glaring issues above - angular 2/4 new person here.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend breaking it into simpler elements.

It looks like you're building one element to manage the entire tree.  If you break it into bits, it'll be easier to build out to the larger structure.

So you'd have a component that shows single market option.  Then an options collection component that ng-repeats a collection of market options.  Then a tournament component...and on outwards.

It could become really large, but if that's the nature of the data, it's the nature of the data.

Once you've got it structured, the code to filter the data to show as needed should become somewhat obvious.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I do have it broken into suitable components but thought for simplicity in the post, i would show the markup as an entire block. Rather than showing different components. Sorry I should have said in the post.